# mysql select distinct rows into a comma delimited list column

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have some sql that brings back tags.  they should have distinct ids, but they don't.... so my current data is like:

```
Microsoft | GGG | 1 | 167
Microsoft | GGG | 1 | 2
Microsoft | GGG | 1 | 1
```

What i would like to do is have only one row come back with the final column concatenated into a delimited list like:

```
Microsoft | GGG | 1 | 167, 2, 1
```

I am using mySQL 5 for this.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking in your flag.  If you asked the wrong question, then evaluate the answer(s) provided, see if it answers the question you asked here, and close out the question by selecting the correct answer.  You can then go ask your *real* question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this, with a `GROUP BY` covering the other three columns:

```
SELECT 
  name,   -- Microsoft
  other,  -- GGG
  other2, -- 1
  GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids
FROM tbl
GROUP BY name, other, other2
```

Comment: And in the event that `ids` is a large set, don't forget to set a large-enough value for: `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;`

Comment: This doesn't give distinct values.

Comment: @geoidesic Not sure where you mean. The question didn't ask for distinct values, but if you read [the `GROUP_CONCAT()` docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) you will find it does support a `DISTINCT` keyword to deduplicate its string return value.