# Mysql, merge content of specific field in resultset, when key matches

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to merge the results of a mysql result set, let em explain with an example:

```
|type|brand|model|color_idx|color|
|car|audi|A4|1|red|
|car|audi|A4|2|green|
|car|audi|A4|3|blue|
|car|audi|A4|4|brown|
```

So ideally, what would like to see, possibly in the returned table, without any manipulation in scripts, is the following:

```
|car|audi|A4|red,green,blue,brown|
```

I could not find anything on the web, i wonder if such functionality exists at all.

```
SELECT type,brand,model,group_concat(color) FROM vehicles WHERE type='car' GROUP BYtype,brand,model,color_idx;
```

This is not really doing the job

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql select distinct rows into a comma delimited list column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343458/mysql-select-distinct-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-column)

Comment: ah thx i did not see that

Comment: presumably, the order of the concatenated result is unimportant?

Comment: well, it is, i should match those against the arguments order in the constructor of a java class, so yes, the order should remain unchanged, i will edit the question as i have just added a color_id

Comment: solved thx, i guess this can be closed as its a dupe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group_concat would be OK.

```
select type,brand,model,group_concat(color)
  from your_table
 group by type,brand,model
```