# MySQL: get all rows and separate by column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi I am still new to working with databases and I need a method to get all rows and separate each column value into array of rows.

**For example:**

```
id col1   col2 ..
1  type1  abc  ..
2  type1  def  .. 
3  type2  ghi  ..
4  type3  jkl  ..
```

Grouping by col1, I am looking for my output to be `[ [ {1}, {2} ], [ {3} ], [ {4} ] ]` with the numbers representing the entire row. Any suggestions on an efficient way to do this without needing to parse the output?

**Edit:**
Expected Output:

```
{
    [ {id:1, col1:type1, col2:abc, ...} , {id:2, col1:type1, col2:def, ...} ],
    [ {id:3, col1:type2, col2:ghi, ...} ],
    [ {id:4, col1:type3, col2:jkl, ...} ]
]
```

Comment: Do you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343458/mysql-select-distinct-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-column ?

Comment: @BHappyBHarsham I have added a more detailed expected output

Comment: add FOR JSON AUTO   with simple select * from table for json auto

Comment: I think you can do this through script, direct with query would be not possible the desired output.

Comment: it not available to mysql db. you can go for sql server 2016 to get this ..check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server